# Flash Builder 4 - Multi-touch

Tags: flash, apache-flex, touch, builder, multi-touch

I want to enable 2-finger-pinch-zoom and 3-finger-drag in my app.

What is the easiest way to implement these basic multi-touch functions? No need for custom gestures, just the two multi-touch functions mentioned above:

2 fingers to zoom
3 fingers to pan.

Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the [input mode](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#inputMode) to [gesture](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/MultitouchInputMode.html#GESTURE), and then listen for the events: [TransformGestureEvent.GesturePan](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TransformGestureEvent.html#GESTURE_PAN) and/or [TransformGestureEvent.GestureZoom](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/TransformGestureEvent.html#GESTURE_ZOOM)

Comment: Will this cause any problems with normal input like mouse and keyboard? Or does it simply add the function of multi-touch to an already working application..

This is to be used on both computers with keyboard/mouse and touch-screens..

Comment: @StianBergLarsen For Keyboard interaction it should make no difference.  What device are you using that supports both Gestures and a mouse simultaneously?

Comment: I've tried adding the code for zooming, but I cant seem to get it working. Nothing happens. (No trace is shown).
In my canvas I've added this: gestureZoom="videoBufferGZoom(event)"
And the function sends a trace. But that doesnt happen. I've added this on creationComplete: Multitouch.inputMode=MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

Comment: This is mainly for desktop use, not android or iOS at the moment.. If that has anything to say.

Comment: @StianBergLarsen Does your hardware support Gestures?  Check to see if gestures are supported: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/Multitouch.html#supportsGestureEvents

Comment: I'm using a SyncMaster LD220z monitor for gestures. Should have multi-touch support...

Comment: The function returns true, so gestureEvents are possible.. Just not working :P hehe

Comment: @StianBergLarsen I don't have any more advice for you.  You could try alternate gestures libraries: http://gestureworks.com/features/open-source-gestures/ but I have no idea if you'll have better luck.

Comment: Today the gestures works. Might have been as simple as a restart that was needed :P
Anyways, zoom gesture works, but it's far from smooth.. It's way too laggy. Even tried with a simple image in a new project, but still unusable because of the lag (200-800ms lagg). Any ideas?

Comment: @StianBergLarsen Nope, no ideas.  There are a lot of moving parts to something like this; and it could be anything including the hardware or the responsiveness of the AIR runtime, or the code.